# Building C++ Executable Visual Studio "The code execution cannot proceed.." SFML

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exe

When I build my project it works on my computer but once I try to give it to a friend to test my project I get these errors:

> "The code execution cannot proceed because MSVCP140D.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."

> "The code execution cannot proceed because VCRUNTIME140D.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."

> "The code execution cannot proceed because ucrtbased.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."

> "The code execution cannot proceed because MSVCP140D.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."

I have tried a lot of things already for example I switched my runtime to Multi-threaded /mt
I am on Visual Studio Community 2022.
I have tried links for Visual Studio 20XX Redistributable package and I cant find one for 2022.

I have been having a lot of problems with VS in general like my extension manager wont load more than half the time.

Does anyone have any idea what I need to do to make the .exe runnable on other computers?

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReport   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(wlocale.obj)   1
> Error   LNK1120 7 unresolved externals  SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\Debug\SFML Game.exe 1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __calloc_dbg SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(xlocale.obj)   1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __calloc_dbg SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\Game.obj    1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __calloc_dbg SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(_tolower.obj)  1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __calloc_dbg SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(locale.obj)    1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __calloc_dbg SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(wlocale.obj)   1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReport   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(xlocale.obj)   1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReport   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\Game.obj    1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReport   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(cout.obj)  1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReport   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(locale.obj)    1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW  SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(xmbtowc.obj)   1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW  SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(StlCompareStringA.obj) 1
> Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW referenced in function __freea_crt   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(StlLCMapStringA.obj)   1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __free_dbg   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(StlCompareStringA.obj) 1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __free_dbg   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(StlLCMapStringA.obj)   1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __free_dbg   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(wlocale.obj)   1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __free_dbg   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(xlocale.obj)   1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __free_dbg   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(xwcsxfrm.obj)  1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __free_dbg   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\Game.obj    1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __free_dbg   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj)   1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __free_dbg   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(cout.obj)  1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __free_dbg   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(locale.obj)    1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __malloc_dbg SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(StlCompareStringA.obj) 1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __malloc_dbg SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(StlLCMapStringA.obj)   1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __malloc_dbg SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(wlocale.obj)   1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __malloc_dbg SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(xlocale.obj)   1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __malloc_dbg SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(xwcsxfrm.obj)  1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __malloc_dbg SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\Game.obj    1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __malloc_dbg SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj)   1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __malloc_dbg SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(cout.obj)  1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __malloc_dbg SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(locale.obj)    1
> Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __realloc_dbg referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl std::locale::_Locimp::_Locimp_Addfac(class std::locale::_Locimp *,class std::locale::facet *,unsigned int)" (?_Locimp_Addfac@_Locimp@locale@std@@CAXPAV123@PAVfacet@23@I@Z)   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(locale.obj)    1
> Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __wcsdup_dbg SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(xstrcoll.obj)  1
> Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __wcsdup_dbg referenced in function __Getctype   SFML Game   D:\Programing\September 2022\Game\SFML Game\libcpmtd.lib(_tolower.obj)  1

Comment: You need to provide the mentioned dll's to your friends computer. This can be done by copying them from your machine or installing the Visual C++ Redistributable https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170
Also what you give your friend is a debug build, give him a release instead ;)

Comment: So... In the last minutes it seems like I broke my project.

Running the project in debug produces these errors:  https://imgur.com/a/9NrbXpT however it still works in the release build.

Comment: When I also build the release version and run the .exe I get this now https://imgur.com/a/YeTKuN6 :cry:

Comment: Please add the error messages as text in the actual question description.

Comment: Its DEBUG dlls - they not be in distributables, only in VS. So, your friend need install VS or manually copy these dlls from your computer

Comment: There you go. I added it.

Comment: So they need to have VS installed on their computer, that seems a bit weird

Comment: Have you tried passing a simple SFML window program to your friends?

Comment: From Microsoft: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/preparing-a-test-machine-to-run-a-debug-executable)

_Debug versions of an application aren't redistributable, and debug versions of the Visual C++ library DLLs are also not redistributable. You may deploy debug versions of applications and Visual C++ DLLs only to your other computers, for the sole purpose of debugging and testing the applications on a computer that doesn't have Visual Studio installed. For more information, see Redistributing Visual C++ files._

Comment: Any  update? Was your problem  solved?

Comment: Yes sorry for the late reply. I was able to figure out how to get the Redistributing Visual C++ Files on my friends computer and the application started to work! Thank you everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I also build the release version and run the .exe I get this now

Use release version library to build your exe instead of debug version lib. Also, you need to put exe lib and dll in the same directory.

Your friend doesn't need to install Visual Studio, but needs the C++ libraries( same version as yours of Visual C++ Redistributable packages  and SFML  DLL)  used to run your program.